# PLAIN + IMAP + SSL Android Java - failed connection

Tags: android, email, imap, javax, jakarta

Я пытаюсь подключиться к почтовому серверу, использующему протокол `imap` по `ssl` и авторизацией методом `plain`.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.***my-server-domain***");
        props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
        props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

        final Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        login,
                        password
                );
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
        Store store = null;
        try {
            store = session.getStore("imap");
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            store.connect();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Но как бы я не пробовал я получаю либо такие ошибки:

```
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1667)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
at jakarta.mail.URLName.getHostAddress(URLName.java:502)
at jakarta.mail.URLName.hashCode(URLName.java:478)
at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:365)
at jakarta.mail.Session.getPasswordAuthentication(Session.java:889)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:325)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
```

Либо одну вот такую (если где-то немного меняю настройки):

```
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
```

Я пробовал менять `imap`, `imaps` и так далее, порт (хотя работает сервер на 993) но все равно не удается подключиться. Интернет в приложении включен в манифесте, так же делал отдельный метод для его проверки и да, он работал.

Мне кажется что я неправильно работаю с `plain` методом и что-то не подключил в `Properties`.

Comment: Приведите полный листинг ошибки, первая очень похожа на банальный `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.